# How do I use Firebase Auth to show user-specific data from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'll share my database structure first:

```
Timetable
   Ladybridge High School, Bolton, UK
      Name: Ladybridge High School
      Town: Bolton
      Country: UK
      User
         Email: rafansari97@gmail.com
         First Name: Raf
         Last Name: Ansari
   St James High School, Bolton, UK
      Name: St James High School
      Town: Bolton
      Country: UK
      User
         Email: raf-a@live.co.uk
         First Name: Raf
         Last Name: Ansari
```

Now, say rafansari97@gmail.com has successfully logged in through Firebase Authentication. How would I go about retrieving its data nested above (Name: Ladybridge High School, Town: Bolton, etc.) without knowing the full path reference i.e. I will only be able to specify "Timetable" as the path? I understand I can build a separate tree which relates user email to the 2nd node but I'd like to avoid that solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current data structure, you'll need to use a query to find the node(s) that match the email address.

Something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Timetable");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("User/Email").equalTo("rafansari97@gmail.com");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey()); // Ladybridge High School, Bolton, UK
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class)); // Ladybridge High School
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The `for` loop in there is needed since multiple nodes might match the given email address. Even if you ensure there's only one match, the API can't know that so you'll need to loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your database model is correct. When you register a user, each unique user gets its own unique id. Model your data using those unique ids which you can get through FirebaseUser.getUniqueId(). If you do that, it will look as follows:

```
Timetable
  ASDNJ2332IWQE23ZXWQ:    
      School: Ladybridge High School, Bolton, UK
      Name: Ladybridge High School
      Town: Bolton
      Country: UK
      User
         Email: rafansari97@gmail.com
         First Name: Raf
         Last Name: Ansari
  SDASFSDGSEGEEFGEGRG:
      School: St James High School, Bolton, UK
      Name: St James High School
      Town: Bolton
      Country: UK
      User
         Email: raf-a@live.co.uk
         First Name: Raf
         Last Name: Ansari
```

So this way, you can get users unqiue id and search your database using that string

Comment: If I implement this solution, I also need to be able to show the Name, Town and Country without referencing the Uid because this same information needs to be accessible to all users, some users will just have extra privileges. Is this still possible?

Comment: Yeah, it is totally possible. If you want to show user info to other users, you just need to loop through each unique id and display its content. If you want to display personal info of the user, you can search and display only searched id

Comment: Frank's solution above was more appropriate for me but I learnt something from your answer too so much appreciated. +1